# How to build an arch that is angled out of Lego?

Tags: technic, building

I am currently working on a MOC for the [USS Orville](https://orville.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Orville) and I am trying to figure out the engines.  I have gone through a couple of iterations on my current version, but it always buckles under its own weight.  The underlying structure is made of [1 x 6 locking hinges](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30388#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) with [2 x 2 brackets](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=44728#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) and connected to the base using technic pieces.  I am trying to make it the scale of the new [Tantive IV](https://shop.lego.com/en-US/product/Tantive-IV-75244) set, i.e. not UCS size, but not micro size either.  Any techniques or ideas would be much appreciated!

[image: Front]

[image: Side]

Comment: Have you tried using technic liftarms? They come in different angles. And are pretty sturdy. https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=P&catString=137&itemBrand=1000

Comment: @JanWindemuth, I started down that path, but I could not get to be thin enough.  The angled liftarm angles are too big for the gentle curve, and using the straight ones requires them to be layered (I was doing layers of 3 so they corners could lock in place) and it was way too thick for the scale I am aiming for.  Maybe there is a better way to connect the liftarms that I am not aware of.

Comment: I see. What about half liftarms? That would be thinner nur Not neccessarrily easier to build.

Comment: @JanWindemuth unfortunately I don't have many of those in my collection, and working with technic in LDD is a pain.  I think I might try axles with connectors.  I have plenty of those plus they interface better with bricks.